# selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element could not be scrolled into view interacting with input using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

I have a site and I need to fill an input field.
Only the field with **37.75** is causing a problem, it is not disabled it has a placeholder and I can interact with it easily myself, but when it comes to selenium, I can't.

I have tried:

```
self.driver.execute_script(f"document.getElementById('product_length').value='{str(depth10)}'")
```

This did nothing

```
pyperclip.copy(str(depth10))
self.driver.find_element_by_id("product_length").click()
pclip.paste()
```

```
self.driver.find_element_by_id("product_length").send_keys(str(depth10))
```

Every find_element_by_id() returned the exception:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <input id="product_length" class="input-text wc_input_decimal" name="_length" type="text"> could not be scrolled into view
```

I used Expected  Conditions & WebdriverWait with `element_to_be_clickable()` but it couldn't find it in 2 minutes

I also tried:

```
actions.move_to_element(element).perform()
```

and

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
```

[image]
*Image of the field*

Image of the HTML:
[image: HTML]

[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MyUcw.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element could not be scrolled into view
```

...implies that the [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) wasn't interactable when you invoked `click()` on it.

---

### Solution

Ideally, to click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.wrap > input#product_length[name='variable_length[1]']"))).send_keys(str(depth10))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='wrap']/input[@id='product_length' and @name='variable_length[1]']"))).send_keys(str(depth10))
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: I used Expected Conditions & WebdriverWait with element_to_be_clickable but it couldn't find it in 2 minutes. I used XPATH and ID, btw the elements was clearly visible and I could click it with my mouse while it couldn't find with expected conditions

Comment: @Alper Here's what you can try. Chcek if scroll is needed to make the element appear in the window. If not that. Open developer tools. press CTRL+F check if typing the `xpath` shows the element, else your xpath is wrong. It may be right, but sometimes, scrollintoview is neccessary. Without looking at the website it's hit and miss.

Comment: @AbhishekRai Thanks for your help, my xpath is correct and I forgot to mention in the question that I also tried scrollIntoView, and actions.move_to_element(element).perform()
but I still can't proceed

Comment: is there a `shadow-root` above your element? Did you check if it is a different `iframe`? Else, right click and copy the `full` xpath`. That's all I can think of.

Comment: @Alper checkout the updated answer and let me know the status

Comment: @DebanjanB I guess I can't see the updated answer, it is still the same suggesting Expected Conditions

Comment: @AbhishekRai I checked and neither of those exist, I tried the full xpath and no changes, thanks for taking your time to help

Comment: @Alper Well. Check the expert's updated answer..and let us know..if it doesn't work. I think he updated his answer with your element names.

Comment: As @AbhishekRai mentioned your locator strategy was hitting the wrong element but **not** the desired element. The element mentioned in the error doesn't matches the element in the snapshot. The XPath needs to be changed. Hence I dropped the idea of using `ID` and included the parent `<span>`

Comment: when you open developer tools..press CTRL+F and type `//input[@id="product_length"]` It selects the element? That is the `xpath`

Comment: @DebanjanB Oh, I pressed CTRL+F in dev tools and it returned 8 of the same id input elements!

Comment: @Alper so you need to select the index of the elements found. For e.g answer =driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath).  answer[index here].send_keys('whatever you want to send)...type of thing..You get it?

Comment: @Alper How did you get it though? Write here. Will help future visitors a lot. Mention the mistake you were making, if any. That is what SO is about. Answer your own question, in fact.